# ctrl-z to suspend running process suddenly not working in tmux panel

Tags: macos, zsh, jobs, tmux, iterm2

Job's running too long, but don't want to terminate it. Before sending the process to background, I usually use ctrl-z in any tmux panel/window wihtout any problem, but for unknown reasons to me, this key combination suddenly stopped working for that particular panel. ctrl-z seems to work on other tmux panels though.

The job's currently running:

```bash
for f in *.webm; do ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i "$f" -map 0 -s hd1080 -c:v libx264 -preset slower -crf 18 -b:a 64k "${f%.webm}".mp4; done
```

Any particular reason why ctrl-z would suddenly stop working?

Comment: Did you enter this entire command directly?  If so, my wild guess is that `for f in *.webm` is shell builtin and is thus not suspendable.

Comment: Yes. Just tested. I still got the same issue when not looping with `for`. The reason I got the issue might be the fact I did, after running the above command, these steps in the following order : 1) ctrl-Z (which paused well), 2) input `bg` (which made FFmpeg still prints on stdout), then ctrl-Z again (which does no longer do anything). I tried ctrl-C and that key combination too does not work. As though sending a process that outputs to stdout, into the background, deactivates any subsequent ctrl-key combination.

Comment: keys like ctrl-c/ctrl-z only affects **foreground** jobs/processes.

Comment: Clear. After executing `bg` I was lured into believing FFmpeg was still a foreground process (due to FFmpeg still outputting to _stdout_). The sensible way to manage jobs that output to default screen, I believe, is to redirect all messages to some logfile—e.g. `> ffmpeg.log 2>&1`—that I would later inspect live from another session/panel using `tail -f ffmpeg.log`. Now, after executing `bg` from where I ran FFmpeg, the command prompt is freed. The reason I wanted to get back my prompt (in the panel running FFmpeg) was to run another cmd that would pause the conversion process after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, the `bg` command you entered made the command become a separate job, so it wouldn't respond to the usual ctrl commands.  If it is still the most recent command, you can run `fg` to bring it back to the foreground to be able to pause it with ctrl-z again.

Otherwise, I'd recommend doing something like

```
ps -aux | grep ffmpeg
```

to get the PID of the process.  Once you have that, you can stop, continue or terminate the process with the `kill` command.

p.s. If you plan to have long-running jobs in the future, you might want to consider using `nohup` and/or redirecting the output to a file.